# golang go.mod issue with indirect package after doing update on packages

Tags: go, hashicorp

Hi guys seems when we using this module we started getting this err

```
# github.com/hashicorp/go-discover/provider/aliyun
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/go-discover@v0.0.0-20200812215701-c4b85f6ed31f/provider/aliyun/aliyun_discover.go:74:8: cannot use map[string]string{…} (value of type map[string]string) as type []ecs.TagType in struct literal
```

and the issue is caused by
`github.com/denverdino/aliyungo v0.0.0-20220905031958-589a058e1592 // indirect`

and I am actually not eveninterested to use this provider only for GKE or EKS

and this works fine with
`github.com/denverdino/aliyungo v0.0.0-20200929080117-4fc2b424761a`

any help on this ? how i could avoid this error and skip this package update when doing `go get -u ./...`